# RxJava execute only one Observable at a time

Tags: java, rx-java

We have window with search field. Every time user inputs something search is performed.

1. Search event is translated to data stream.
2. On every new search we need to start async network operation and close previous. How to archive this effect?

Edit1: Here's what I've tried. It executes all observables! Not the only last one, where is a mistake?

```
PublishSubject<Integer> subject = PublishSubject.create();

subject.switchMap(integer -> Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "-" + integer + "-";
})).subscribe(s -> System.out.print(s));
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) subject.onNext(i);
```

Comment: I am still a beginner myself, but couldn't you instead observe the user search input instead and debounce that and then perform searches with the debounced user input?

Comment: @Andreas Yes, it is a half of what I need. Also there must be only one execution at a time etc. each new value cancels previous

Comment: You may want to do both `debounce` and `switchMap` to avoid searching after each keypress as well as cancel old searches.

Comment: @akarnokd please check my edit

Comment: all the observables will be executed because the flow is synchronous. As per my answer you need `subscribeOn` inside the `switchMap`.

Comment: @DaveMoten I removed the line for the reason - it doesn't print anything at all.. How can this be possible?

Comment: If you are running this in a `main` method then put a `Thread.sleep` at the end to get the process to hang around while the background activity happens.

Comment: @DaveMoten
Aaaaa.... I understand.. that execution of program ends before rxJava. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `PublishSubject` with `switchMap`:

```
PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();
subject
  .switchMap(
    x -> networkOperationObservable(x)
           .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io))
  .subscribe(subscriber);
```

To get the most out of this `networkOperationObservable` would respond sensibly to an `unsubscribe` call (as in close the `Socket` or whatever). `Observable.using` is the tool of choice for that generally.

Answer (score 0):

`PublishSubject` is exactly what you need. It is an `Observable` you can add events to at any time.

Create it:

```
private Subject<String, String> filteringSubject = PublishSubject.create();
```

Then use `Observable.throttleWithTimeout()`operator:

```
Subscriber<String> filteringSubscriber = new DefaultSubscriber<>();
filteringSubject
    .throttleWithTimeout(250, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .doOnNext(new Action1<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(String text) {
            //make a network call
        }
     })
     .subscribe(filteringSubscriber);
```

Usage:

```
filteringSubject.onNext(text);
```

Comment: Ok, then `flatMap` `String` to network call and subscribe whole `Obsevable` with real `Subscriber`, not the fake one.